# Can I use "a case in" instead of "a case for" in the mentioned context?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have conducted an argument about vulnerability, which also implies that dishonesty is praiseworthy. In the next sentence I say:

> A case in praise of dishonesty?!

And I mean to say, with a satirical connotation, that what is said also implies that sometimes dishonesty is actually good.

I think the common phrase is "a case for" but I want to use "in praise of dishonesty" as it refers to another significant text. So can I say "a case in praise of"? Or maybe other suggestions?

Comment: *A case in praise of...* isn't idiomatic. *A case for* and *in praise of* simply express different meanings. First you have to decide what you want to say.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely difficult to answer a question so murky.

First, the idiom **make a case for {noun or gerund}** means to **present an argument in support of {noun or gerund}}**. In the meaning of **case** as an **argument**, it must be followed by **for** or **against.**

Second, **case** in the sense of **example** usually takes **of** rather than **in**.

Third, sentence fragments such as yours are discouraged because, lacking a verb, they have little meaning outside of context. You have given very little context.

Fourth, what meaning do you actually intend? Are you trying to say to say that a particular case shows that dishonesty is always praiseworthy? Then say so. Are you trying to say that a particular case shows that dishonesty is sometimes praiseworthy? Then say so.